# Use commands requiring Connect-AzureAD in Powershell job

Tags: powershell

After running `Connect-AzureAD` I can run AzureAd commands.
However, when running these commands

```
Connect-AzureAD -accountid myusername@email.tld
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId myusername@email.tld }
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Receive-Job $job
```

I then get this error

```
You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.
```

How can I run Get-AzureADUser in a PowerShell Job?

Comment: The job has a different scope. On the scope of your job you have never connected to Azure AD.

Comment: How do I pass in the AzureAD connection to the job scope?

Answer (score 0):

Have to run the initializationscript with connect-azuread inside of it. Also use the `using` scope for the job to pull the variable. Example:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-AzureAdUser -SearchString $using:user } -InitializationScript { Connect-AzureAD }
```